# Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0) in the 'ema' function. It must be > 0

Tags: pine-script

The error in the title only occurs when the chart is using the 8h or 12h timeframes. Any timeframe below them and my script works just fine. Now, there are a lot of EMA functions throughout, and I quickly skimmed through my script, I don't believe that there should be any reason why any of their lengths should be 0. The whole script is very long, but it's better than trying to only put the relevant parts since I may miss something. I hope you understand, and big thank you in advance.

Disclaimer: Most of the script isn't my original creation, it is an amalgamation of many different indicators. I just put them together, changing a few things.

Link is here: https://0bin.net/paste/VSK9WtWJ#fFy+cxUpxXTnMtJlD1ZjsMeHOiP9pIMr0einbf5qCF7

I would've used pastebin but it's filters detected something offensive for whatever reason, I promise there's nothing offensive in the script.

The paste will be gone in a month, which should be more than enough time to get an answer (or not).

Comment: > The whole script is very long, but it's better than trying to only put
> the relevant parts since I may miss something. 

It will be easier for others to help you find the issue if you'll isolate the error with a minimum amount of code instead of inspecting 700 lines script. Delete the code parts and see if the error persists until you'll have a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of places where the length is manipulated and it is possible to get to zero

My suggestion is to find all the spots where the there is math done on the length and change it to max(1,length) so the minimum value is 1.

As you said, it is littered with EMA's and many of them nested in functions.